# SQL Auto Increment column based on composite primary key

Tags: sql, composite-primary-key, h2db

Is it possible to increment a seperate column (not PK) when the composite PK changes?

Example:

```
colA|| colB || counter
----------------------
 1  || 2    ||  1
----------------------
 4 ||  3    || 1
----------------------
 1 ||  3    || 2
```

Here the composite PK is (colA,colB). Please let me know if this is possible

Comment: Why would a primary key be mutating? If it is, then it's not a primary key.

Comment: Oh sorry please see edit in example

Comment: What platform is this?

Comment: H2 Database engine

Comment: I'm not familiar with H2. There are 2 approaches typically used. Both involve using a surrogate key. One approach is to add a surrogate key and an "on update" trigger, and compare rows in the trigger's virtual tables. With this, you will be updating the same rows, so you must manage recursion. The alternate approach is to use an "instead of" trigger, if your platform supports it, and avoid the recursion that way.